# label frame not changing programmatically which is added in storyboard

Tags: ios9, xcode7, frame, uistoryboard

Can anybody tell me how to change frame of any controls programmatically which is added in storyboard for **iOS 9**.

Currently, mylable frame which is in storyboard inside UIView.

```
mylabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 45, 290, 30)
```

I need to change frame of mylabel on button's action method.

```
mylabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 80, 290, 100)
```

But, it didn't change.

Comment: @UmaMadhavi Yeah..!! it's working before, but not now. This mylabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 45, 290, 30) is given in storyboard not programmatically. And now i have to change frame programmatically which is not done when i  do this mylabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 80, 290, 100) programmatically .

Comment: so you can change programmatically by assigning property @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *mylabel;

Comment: Already assign @property, still no changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because You have added autolayout constraint into  the control thats why it is automatically resizing . If you want to set frame programmatically then better to remove constraint and then creating iboutlet and doing same way ..it will work.

Thanks.